# Get 3 row ID's via ARRAY_A

Tags: wpdb, array, select

Below query works fine. But how can I **select the 3 results separately** with the **array_number**?

I need to separate the 3 results correct with help from the array_number. But do not know how.

```
$records = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT * FROM wp_rdp_participants_answers AS answ 
INNER JOIN wp_rdp_game_images AS game ON game.image_id = answ.image_id
WHERE answ.game_id = $i 
&& answ.answer_time LIKE '$day%' 
AND answ.answer = game.correct_answer
ORDER BY answ.answer_time ASC 
LIMIT 3", ARRAY_A);

if(count($records) > 0){
    foreach($records as $rec){      

    echo $rec->user_id.' - '. $rec->answer_time.' - '.$rec->answer.' - '. $rec->correct_answer. '<br>' ;
    }
}
```

**How do I get now array[0] , array[1], array[2] ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errm...

```
$item_1 = $records[0];
$item_2 = $records[1];
$item_3 = $records[2];

// e.g.
echo $item_2->answer_time;
```

Comment: $item_0 = $records[0];
$item_1 = $records[1];
$item_2 = $records[2];
echo $item_0->user_email.' <br>' ;  
echo $item_1->user_email.' <br>' ; 
echo $item_2->user_email.' <br>' ; results in:
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in .. on line 15

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ... on line 16

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in .. on line 17

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/deb96951n2/domains/xxxxxx.nl/public_html/rdp/wp-content/plugins/rdp-plugin/includes/test.php on line 18

Comment: Remove `, ARRAY_A` from your original code.

Comment: Still getting errors: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in xxx on line 18
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in xxx on line 19
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxx on line 21
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxx on line 21
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxx on line 22
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxx on line 22

Comment: Because the result set is empty - my code was just to demonstrate the concept. You should still check `count( $records )`